# using some of the asp.net membership tools and log in security

Tags: sql, asp.net, authentication, membership

Hello guys I wanted to ask a few things because I want to upgrade my log in security . First of all this is how my log in security looks like atm -

Sql query compares the user input `( pass / name / id )` to my data base and if its correct he gets 2 values and redirected to the main restricted page.  one of the values is a random value from a function that stores a limited amount of such values ( each time it picks a random 1 and returns it to the user upon successfull log in ) , and the other value is 1 of the input fields ( like company ID for example ) 
both of those stored in  sessions ( hopefully its not an easy to gain the data stored in those from a hacker? )   and on each of the  restricted pages, i use on the page load event 2 terms :

```
Session ( "the ID" ) <> "" 
 isLegit ( session ( "the random code" )  <>  "false"
```

I am still learning about security and i guess my current method is bad? 
And thats where my second question comes to play ,  i been reading about microsoft's memebership and wanted to use some of the stuff included , but even after reading about how it works i find myself failing to implant it on my site .
I got pretty long register form and well the site designed in some way, and if i try putting the log in controls from visual studio i cant get them to look like part of the page.

I read that there is a way to keep my site as it is and to use
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("test", false);
to force membership or something of this sort?
Is such a thing possiblr without having to use the log in tools and storing additional log in data ( beside what i have on my sql data base )?

p.s I am using asp.net with vb  on visual studio with MS sql server

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these articles:

- Introduction to Membership http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy(v=vs.100).aspx
- Sample Membership Provider Implementation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44w5aswa(v=vs.100).aspx
- Introduction to Membership http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw292whz(v=vs.100).aspx

If you are willing to create another table that would hold the user information it should be really straight-forward, works out of the box.

You would need to take out the checks you have in the code, though.